# Implementing native SwiftUI which will eventually returns result into flutter app

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, swiftui

I am implementing face liveness detector for detecting real profile and detect fake profile for one of my projects. So face liveness detector library is only present in native ios and I installed is through spm packages of swift. I successfully rendered that SwiftUI using method channels of flutter. But I am stucked at one point that when face liveness completes its working after that I want to pass the result in form of strings. and   I do not know how to do it in native Ios swift code as I am very new to swift language as well as its core concepts. I tried using delegate pattern swift but no luck I am not getting result in my ViewControllers. Anyone please help me as I am stucked in this problem for more than week. This is how write my code in swift.

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Amplify
import AWSCognitoAuthPlugin

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate, FaceLivenessResultDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
      let controller: FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
      let methodChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "LIVE_VERIFICATION_CHANNEL", binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
      methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler { [weak self] (call, result) in
            if call.method == "startLiveVerification" {
                guard let args = call.arguments as? [String: Any],
                      let sessionId = args["sessionId"] as? String else {
                                 result(FlutterError(code: "INVALID_ARGUMENT", message: "Invalid session Id",details: nil))
                                    return
                                }
                print("session id is \(sessionId)")
                let faceLivenessController = FaceLiveDetectionController(sessionId: sessionId)
                controller.present(faceLivenessController,
                                                                animated: true,
                                                                completion: nil)
            } else {
              result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
            }
          }
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
    func resultCallback(_ result: String) {
        print("you are in result \(result)")
    }
}
```

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class FaceLiveDetectionController: UIHostingController<FaceLivenessDetectionView>, FaceLivenessDelgate {
    var sessionId: String?
    var delegate: FaceLivenessResultDelegate?
    func verificationCallback(_ result: String) {
        delegate?.resultCallback(result)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
            self.sessionId = nil
            rootView = FaceLivenessDetectionView(
                sessionId: sessionId
            )
        }

        init(sessionId: String) {
            self.sessionId = sessionId
            super.init(
                rootView: FaceLivenessDetectionView(
                    sessionId: sessionId
                )
            )
        }
    func facelivenessCallback(_ result: String) {
        print("you are here--> \(result)")
        verificationCallback(result)
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI
import FaceLiveness

struct FaceLivenessDetectionView: View {
    @State private var isPresentingLiveness = true
    var sessionId: String?
     weak var delegate: FaceLivenessDelgate?
    var body: some View {
        if let livenessSessionId = sessionId {
            FaceLivenessDetectorView(
                sessionID: livenessSessionId,
                region: "ap-south-1",
                disableStartView: true,
                isPresented: $isPresentingLiveness,
                onCompletion: { result in
                    switch result {
                    case .success:
                        delegate?.facelivenessCallback("success")
                        print("you are in success -->")
                    case .failure(let error):
                        delegate?.facelivenessCallback("error")
                        print("you are in error")
                    default:
                        delegate?.facelivenessCallback("error")
                        print("Face Liveness Session default")
                    }
                }
            )
        } else {
            Text("Liveness session not started")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.all/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
        }
      }
    init(sessionId: String?) {
            self.sessionId = sessionId
        }
}
```